# Difference between std::boolalpha vs std::ios::boolalpha

Tags: c++

I understood that we can use both options below to change the `boolalpha` flag, but why do we need to qualify `ios_base` in the `setf()` function and can't use `std::boolalpha` within the function parameter?

```cpp
std::cout << std::boolalpha; //using manipulator
std::cout.setf(ios_base::boolalpha); // we can't use std::cout.setf(std::boolalpha);
```

Comment: Look at the documentation of `setf`: It takes a `fmtflags`, not a manipulator. `std::boolalpha` is a manipulator. `ios_base::boolalpha` is a `fmtflags`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::boolalpha` is a stream function object (also known as a manipulator) that sets the `boolalpha` flag on a stream. This flag causes boolean values to be written out as `"true"` or `"false"` rather than as `"1"` or `"0"`.

The `setf()` function is a member function of the `std::ios_base` class, which is the base class for all stream classes. The `setf()` function is used to set various formatting flags on a stream, including the `boolalpha` flag. The first argument to `setf()` is an enumeration value that specifies which flag to set.

In this case, `ios_base::boolalpha` is the enumeration value that represents the `boolalpha` flag, so `std::cout.setf(ios_base::boolalpha)` sets the `boolalpha` flag on the `std::cout` stream.

The reason you can't use `std::boolalpha` within the function parameter, is that `std::boolalpha` is a manipulator, and `setf()` expects the enumeration type as its argument, not a manipulator.

Additionally, a manipulator can be used to simply change the flag, unlike `setf()` that is meant to be used as a more powerful and general set of operations.